# How I can I programmatically replace data in one column with data in another column using R?

Tags: r, transformation

I am currently working with pivoted Census data and have discovered that the data from 2010-2016 is one column off from the data that has been recorded from 2017-2019. To explain in further detail, there is data that is listed for the column DP05_0004E for the Years 2010 through 2016 that should be the values in DP05_0005E. This is the same case for data in those years from 2010 through 2016 for DP05_0005E to DP05_0006E, and so on. The data is being placed in a column that is one numeric value lower than it should be.

How can I get it so I have the data DP05_0004E appear in DP05_0005E, and so on for all the columns where this is necessary? I've attached a data file screenshot to illustrate the problem I am dealing with. Dput output is below:

```html
structure(list(GEO_ID = c("0100000US", "0100000US", "0100000US", 
"0100000US", "0100000US", "0100000US", "0100000US", "0100000US", 
"0100000US", "0100000US"), NAME = c("United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States"
), DP05_0004E = c("20131420", "20170377", "20137884", "20052112", 
"19973711", "19912018", "19866960", "97", "97", "97"), DP05_0005E = c("20116654", 
"20207046", "20311310", "20409060", "20460355", "20501982", "20508363", 
"19853515", "19836850", "19767670"), DP05_0006E = c("20643730", 
"20631572", "20647280", "20672609", "20698883", "20679786", "20664537", 
"20445122", "20311494", "20157477"), DP05_0007E = c("22132691", 
"22083463", "21930781", "21715074", "21510534", "21354481", "21256545", 
"20713111", "20817419", "20927278"), DP05_0008E = c("21214118", 
"21463191", "21775439", "22099887", "22407472", "22604232", "22612610", 
"21219050", "21204226", "21208186"), DP05_0009E = c("40191013", 
"40668821", "41184290", "41711277", "42310182", "42881649", "43397907", 
"22501965", "22286970", "22015108"), DP05_0010E = c("42206141", 
"41683228", "41227505", "40874162", "40723040", "40651910", "40548400", 
"44044173", "44567976", "45030415"), DP05_0011E = c("44302697", 
"44579668", "44646979", "44506268", "44248186", "43895858", "43460466", 
"40656419", "40763210", "40978831"), DP05_0012E = c("18817728", 
"19215139", "19680816", "20165892", "20623001", "21001947", "21291513", 
"43091143", "42589573", "42072620"), DP05_0013E = c("15459667", 
"16292447", "16924986", "17479211", "17973759", "18415681", "18770229", 
"21523460", "21611374", "21654255"), DP05_0014E = c("20493467", 
"21152731", "22012061", "22957030", "23993984", "25135167", "26355308", 
"19224060", "19675357", "20102159"), Year = c("2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example along with expected output (instead of images)

Comment: Can you share some snippets of your data? Use `dput(df)`

Comment: Added the dput output!

Comment: You mention "for the Years 2010 through 2016" and "in those years from 2010 through 2016." Is there other data in the data set for other years that is not misaligned? In other words, should the adjustment check for year before updating the value?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be use `if_else` with a condition inside `mutate`

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    DP05_0004E = if_else("your condition",DP05_0005E,DP05_0004E),
    DP05_0005E = if_else("your condition",DP05_0006E,DP05_0005E)  
  )
```